# How can get current element without id and class?

Tags: javascript, qt, execcommand

I use an editable `QWebView` and write some text on it. I want to get current element that text cursor point to it and do some changes. For example text cursor is in a `<p>` tag that haven't any Id or class. I want to get this paragraph and set it's display to none for example.

**How can I get the current element that haven't any Id or class?**

I tried: `this.style.display="none"` it didn't work, but when I try `document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.display="none"` it works. And I don't know how can i get the current element.

Point that I want to do this just with javascript, not jquery. and without any click or etc. Is it possible? How can i do this?

How does execCommand work? for example how execCommand justifyRight get the current element?

This is my code:

```
QWebFrame *frame = p->webView->page()->mainFrame();
QString js = QString("this.style.display='none'");
frame->evaluateJavaScript(js);
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the context of using this.style.display ?

Comment: You are probable using this out of context, read about this here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: In my project execCommand works fine, do you know how execCommand get the current element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of an editable web page, ideally we'd want to be able to ask the `QWebFrame` in what `QWebElement` is the caret, at any time. Then we could tweak this element with C++ code.

Unfortunately, according to the documentation, no such method is provided.

Anyway, there's a  workaround in webkit's javascript since we can access the user selection or the caret's position in the DOM with `window.getSelection()`. Here's some code that finds the nearest `<p>` tag above the selection and changes its style as needed:

```
  QString js=
  "  var node = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer;"
  "  while (node) {"
  "    if (node.nodeName.toUpperCase()=='P') {"
  "      node.style.display='none';"
  "      break;"
  "    }"
  "    node=node.parentNode;" 
  "  }" ;

  QVariant res = page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(js);
```

You might want to generalize it to take node types and styles as parameters, and possibly test it a bit (I'm no JS expert), but the I believe the principle is sound.